# Clone elements but they must have "unique properties"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8MyX/)

Here's my setup so far:

I can preview the message for the intended recipient. However, I need the functionality to dynamically add more recipients. I pretty much have the basic functionality of that done.

**Problem #1:** My problem is whenever I add a new recipient, the `keyup` no longer works for the subsequent fields.

**Problem #2:** Also, how do I clear the fields before I clone the first div? Or do I use a different method and not use `.clone()`?

**Problem #3:** Lastly, how do I make each field unique? Notice in my script file and the classes I used, they are all the same so whatever I input in the first field will copied to ALL previews.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8MyX/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you must use on() event delegation so keyup works on dynamic elements and to type on it's unique text you must find the sub_container using .closest()

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.name', function (e) {
    var input = $(this).val().replace(/[\n]/g, '<br />');
    $(this).closest('.sub_container').find('.preview_name').html(input);
});
$(document).on('keyup', '.message', function (e) {
    var input = $(this).val().replace(/[\n]/g, '<br />');
    $(this).closest('.sub_container').find('.preview_message').html(input);
});
$('.add_new').click(function (e) {
    //var container = $('.sub_container').html();
    //$('.container').append(container);
    $('.sub_container').first().clone().appendTo('.container').find('input').val('');
    $('.preview_message').last().html('');
    $('.preview_name').last().html('');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/Z8MyX/2/)

Comment: No need for on, simply set clone to true, and use closest as anton recommended to target the relevant field.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add `.clone(true)` to clone the event listeners attached to the element.

```
$('.add_new').click(function(e) {
        //var container = $('.sub_container').html();
        //$('.container').append(container);
        $('.sub_container').first().clone().appendTo('.container');
});
```

Becomes

```
$('.add_new').click(function(e) {
        //var container = $('.sub_container').html();
        //$('.container').append(container);
        $('.sub_container').first().clone(true).appendTo('.container');
    });
```

**[Updated Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8MyX/1/)**

[.clone() docs.](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

Answer (score 1):

event delegation

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.name', function (e) {
    var input = $(this).val().replace(/[\n]/g, '<br />');
    $(this).closest('.sub_container').find('.preview_name').html(input);
});
$(document).on('keyup', '.message', function (e) {
    var input = $(this).val().replace(/[\n]/g, '<br />');
    $(this).closest('.sub_container').find('.preview_message').html(input);
});


$(document).on('click', '.add_new', function (e) {
    //var container = $('.sub_container').html();
    //$('.container').append(container);
    $('.sub_container').first().clone().appendTo('.container').find(':input').val('');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PqGyd/)

Comment: Thanks. How do I clear the input fields before I clone? So that whenever I add a new recipient, it will be a blank form.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a parent().parent() it will only update the preview area next to form elements you are currently editing:

http://jsfiddle.net/Z8MyX/3/

```
$('.name').keyup(function(e) {
        var input = $(this).val().replace(/[\n]/g,'<br />');
        $('.preview_name').html(input);
    });

    $('.message').keyup(function(e) {
        var input = $(this).val().replace(/[\n]/g,'<br />');
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.preview_message').html(input);
    });

    $('.add_new').click(function(e) {
        //var container = $('.sub_container').html();
        //$('.container').append(container);
        $('.sub_container').first().clone(true).appendTo('.container');
    });
```